# x86 Using .IF , .ELSE , and .ELSEIF to compare two numbers

Tags: if-statement, assembly, x86, masm

I am given two DWORD values and will compare both of them using `.IF`, `.ELSE`, `.ELSEIF` to see which number is larger or if they are both equal. For example, two prompts are called to screen, which are "Enter Number 1" and "Enter Number 2". Number 1 and Number 2 are stored into separate registers using `eax` for *num1* and `ecx` for *num2*. IF `eax` and `ecx` are equal, the equal prompt is called.
If they aren't, then here's where `.ELSEIF` comes in. `eax` is compared to `ecx` and vice versa.

The only problem is that number two is always larger than the first value, if they are not equal.

```
include asmlib.inc
.data

Prompt  BYTE    " Enter a number ", 0     ;Type number 1
Prompt2 BYTE    " Enter another number ", 0 ;Type number 2
Large   BYTE    " Is larger ", 0 ;Larger number output
Equal   BYTE    " Is equal", 0  ;Numbers are equal output
num1    DWORD ? ;Number 1 is num1
num2    DWORD ? ;Number 2 is num2

.code
main PROC

mov edx, OFFSET Prompt ;Enter first number
call writeLine
call readInt
mov num1, eax
endl

mov edx, OFFSET Prompt2 ;Enter second num
call writeLine
call readInt
mov num2, ecx
endl

.IF  eax == ecx
mov edx, OFFSET Equal   ;display Equal output
call writeString    ;display line
.ENDIF 

.IF ecx > eax && eax < ecx
mov ecx, num2
call    writeInt
mov edx, OFFSET Large
call    writeString

.ELSEIF ecx < eax && eax > ecx
mov eax, num1
call    writeInt
mov edx, OFFSET Large
call    writeString
.ENDIF

exit
main ENDP
end main
```

Comment: First, you need to compare only `eax < ecx`, not both ways (as in `eax < ecx && ecx > eax`). Next, you should copy the value of the larger value to the same register. I don't know, which register writeInt expects the argument, but it should be the same in both cases. Further, the correct value is already either in the correct register, or in the other register, meaning that there's no need to load from memory. Thus `mov eax, ecx` or `mov ecx, eax` in only one of the branches, or even `swap ecx, eax`. Either way, you can save code by `.IF cond; swap; .ENDIF`

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> mov edx, OFFSET Prompt2 ;Enter second num
> call writeLine
> call readInt
> mov num2, ecx
> ```

Everything the `.IF`, `.ELSEIF`, `.ELSE`, or `.ENDIF` can do is invalidated because of an error retrieving the program's input.
*readInt* returns the integer in the `EAX` register, and so your `mov num2, ecx` instruction should read `mov num2, eax`

> The only problem is that number two is always larger than the first value, if they are not equal.

If `ecx > eax` you display "Is larger", and if `ecx < eax` you also display "Is larger". What did you expect?

- Prior to your first `.IF  eax == ecx` instructions, you should load `EAX` from *num1* and `ECX` from *num2*.
- If the numbers happen to be equal, you don't want to use `.ENDIF`, because it makes you fall through and additionally (and needlessly) execute the comparison for "larger than".

```
mov eax, num1
mov ecx, num2
.IF eax == ecx
    mov     edx, OFFSET Equal
    call    writeString
.ELSEIF eax > ecx
    call    writeInt
    mov     edx, OFFSET Large
    call    writeString
    mov     eax, ecx        ; ecx = num2
    call    writeInt
.ENDIF
```